# Linking CMake project to Make project using custom command or custom target

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a GUI as a wrapper for some command line program previously written. The cmd line program uses makefiles while the gui i'm writing is using cmake. The file structure looks like this:

```
project
├──gui
│  ├── CMakeLists.txt
├──instruments
│  ├── CORE.o
│  └── makefile
└──session
   ├── SESSION.o
   └── makefile
```

I need to link to the SESSION.o and CORE.o files from the CMakeLists.txt file. I can achieve this using:

```cmake
target_link_libraries(gui PRIVATE
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../session/SESSION.o
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../instruments/CORE.o)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../session
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../instruments)
```

However, if SESSION.o or CORE.o are not built, I'd like cmake to call make in those directories.

I've tried variations of:

```cmake
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../session/SESSION.o PRE_LINK
                    COMMAND make -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../session SESSION.o)
```

and

```cmake
# Trying to autobuild the session and core code. having lots of trouble
add_custom_target(SESSION.o ALL
                    COMMAND make -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../session SESSION.o)
```

Both of which either present errors or cmake doesn't recognize as a rule to make SESSION.o when trying to link the library.

How should I be connecting these? I'm fine with attempting to build the projects every time, independent of any change in dependencies.

Comment: side-question, why are you producing and linking object files when you could be making static libraries?

Comment: Just drop these `Makefile` (s) and build everything w/ CMake :-)

Answer (score 0):

For your attempt with `add_custom_command`, it looks like you're trying to use [the build-events signature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) (given that you're using the `PRE_LINK` argument, which is only valid for the build-events signature and not the generating-files signature). In that case, you need to follow the rest of that signature too: you haven't specified a target for the build event to be a build event for. Ex.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET gui PRE_LINK
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../session/SESSION.o
  COMMAND make -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../session SESSION.o
)
```

You probably want to throw in the `VERBATIM` argument just to be safe.

As for your `add_custom_target` attempt, you don't need to say `COMMAND` for the first command. And you'd need to [`add_dependencies(gui SESSION.o)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) to make CMake generate a buildsystem where the `SESSION.o` target is "built" before `gui`.